# Change onClickListener dynamically in handleMessage depending on Message

Tags: android

I have an Activity with Android.os.Handler, which is used for communication with an openGL thread. 
I want to get messages from the opengl thread and draw some GUI in the activity depending on the message data, so I do:

```
Handler handle = new Handler(new Handler.Callback(){
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg){
            // update  GUI like
            TextView v1 = (TextView) GamescreenActivity .this.findViewById(R.id.mytextview)
            // then what I actually would like to do but it does not work:
            Button b = (Button) GamescreenActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
            b.setOnClickListener(null);
            if (msg.what == MY_OWN_CONSTANT) { 
                b.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(msg));
            }
        }
View.OnClickListener getOnClickDoSomething(final Message msg)  {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            makeDialog(msg);
        }
    };
}
private void makeDialog(Message msg) {      
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GamescreenActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage("yo")
    .setTitle(""+ msg.what);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

I hope it is clear what i'm trying to achieve. What I get by now is msg being null in the makeDialog methode almost all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I get by now is msg being null in the makeDialog methode almost all the time.

I believe the Message has already been recycled when this happens. Let's create a local copy of `msg` and modify your code a little to make it more efficient. First create a new field variable:

```
Message message;
```

Next change your if-else block:

```
if (msg.what == MY_OWN_CONSTANT) { 
    message = Message.obtain(msg);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GamescreenActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("yo")
                    .setTitle(""+ message.what)
                    .show();
            message.recycle(); // Recycle our message when we're done
        }
    });
}
else {
    b.setOnClickListener(null);
}
```